# pipe() function in linux

Tags: linux, pipe

My question regards pipe() function in linux: http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

My question is: "is there only ONE pipe in linux?". I mean, if I have multiple processes that write to pipe, is it the same pipe, meaning that once I read data from the pipe, I may get data from different processes in the same read() operation?

Comment: This is a very confused question. Why not include whatever made you think this in the first place? Do you have a program that is showing you data from different processes?

Answer (score 5):

No. The `pipe()` function creates a new pipe with two ends.

What can happen is that the file descriptor can be duplicated. The `dup`, `dup2` functions can do this. `fork` does it too.

If you somehow have two programs with duplicated pipe file descriptors then yes, both of them will show up in the pipe's output.

It is the same thing as a terminal window showing output from programs running in the foreground and background.

Comment: so what you're saying is that the child process that is created in fork() inherits the file-descriptors of the pipe so it's actually exactly the same data?

Comment: @CrazySynthax: Just like how programs inherit the file-descriptors of the terminal from your shell when you launch a new program from the command line. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Read not only [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), but also [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) and most importantly [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

> I mean, if I have multiple processes that write to pipe

generally, you should not make that possible...

> is it the same pipe, meaning that once I read data from the pipe, I may get data from different processes in the same read() operation?

Yes, but you usually don't do that.